# How to use getattr and string for calling class?

Tags: python

```
somelist=[1,2,3,4,5]

class HI:
    a="QWERTY"

def test(wannacall):
    test1="testing"+str(wannacall)
    print(getattr(test1,"a")) #<- this part makes error 'str' object has no attribute 'a'.

testing1=HI()
test(somelist[0])
```

I know why this error happens, but I can't solve this.
(Sorry for my bad English.)

Edit: I know why that error happens, but I want to make code shorter than this:

```
somelist=[1,2,3,4,5]

class HI:
    a="QWERTY"

def test(wannacall):
    if wannacall==1:
        print(getattr(testing1,"a"))
    test1="testing"+str(wannacall)

testing1=HI()
test(somelist[0])
```

because the code will be longer if there are more classes. (ex: `testing2`, `testing3`, `testing4`).

**+++** I solved this with `eval()` — my friend helped me.

```
print(getattr(eval(test1),"a"))
```

Comment: why don't you pass `testing1` to `test`?

Comment: test1 is a string. You instance of the class HI is testing1. Take care about naming your variables!

Comment: So.. Can't i change that test1's type to '\_\_main\_\_.HI'?

Comment: @MellDa you shouldn't be designing your program this way to begin with. Why don't you just *pass the object?* Why use a string that happens to be the name of the object in the global scope?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh thanks, I will try that :)

Comment: There is almost certainly a better way of doing this than using `eval()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from not using getattr correctly.

The getattr() method takes multiple parameters:

1.object - object whose named attribute's value is to be returned
For example:

```
HI= HI() #declare the class 
getattr(HI,.....)
```

2.name - a string that contains the attribute's name
For example:

```
getattr(HI, "a", ...)
```

3.default (Optional) - value that is returned when the named attribute is not found
For example:

```
getattr(HI, "a", "QRDefult")
```

What you are doing in your way is your using a string as the first parameter instead of an object. Just because your string has the same name as your object doesn't mean its an object.

you can do this instead

```
somelist=[1,2,3,4,5]
class HI:
    b="QWERTY"



def test(object, wannacall):
    test1="testing" + str(wannacall)
    print(test1)
    print(getattr(object,"b")) #<- this part makes error 'str' object has no attribute 'a'.


object=HI()
test(object,somelist[0])
```